# What is the fastest and most cost effective way of converting liquidated BTC into a stable or wBTC during times of high volatility?

Tags: solidity, api

I could only find this related question:

[How to swap BTC to WBTC](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76833/how-to-swap-btc-to-wbtc)

But this relates to reducing risk in finding a fast, automated way in times of likely, high volatility.

1. It needs to be automated using a trustworthy partner/API
2. We need to fixate the USD value asap => convert it to any trustworthy stable coin (preferably with minimal costs).
3. We can't use CEX accounts, as this requires time in the supply flow, which may take too much time.
4. Our goal is to have something like 10 minutes max for the whole swap procedure. The faster the better.

Thank you in advance for any help!