# How to convert testnet BTC to WBTC?

Tags: testnets, decentralized-exchange, bitcoin, wrapped-tokens

How can I convert my test **BTC** to **WBTC** so that I can then communicate with **EVM Ethereum**?? Should I use a particular **DEX** over others or are there methods that already exist in the bitcoin libraries out there?

How can I convert my test BTC to WBTC so that I can then communicate with EVM Ethereum?? Should I use a particular DEX over others or are there methods that already exist in the bitcoin libraries out there?

> I'm developing a non-custodial crypto wallet, so any advice, useful
> links and development guides are welcome :)

Comment: You missed important testnet in title and tags. Unless you mean duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76833/how-to-swap-btc-to-wbtc

Answer (score 0):

Based on your non custodial example you are better off using a DEX or bridge like Changelly, a number of CEXs will also allow you to swap between BTC - WBTC but keep in mind the demand for test net coins will be relatively low.